# itertools.tee not making copies of groupby iterator

Tags: python, python-itertools

I just learnt that `itertools.tee()` can be used to make any number of copies of a given iterator.

So I am trying to create two copies of groupby and loop over each one of them. However, the second iterator returns no groups.

```
import itertools
l = [("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("b", 4)]
groups = itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x[0])

groups1, groups2 = itertools.tee(groups, 2)

for key, group in groups1:
    print(key + ": " + str(list(group)))

for key, group in groups2:
    print(key + ": " + str(list(group)))
```

Also, I found this in the docs and I couldn't exactly understand when `tee()` is not faster than `list()`

> This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on
>   how much temporary data needs to be stored). In general, if one
>   iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts,
>   it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it explains it, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991852/unexpected-behavior-of-itertools-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is a nested iterator; the "outer" returns a sequence of `_grouper` objects, each of which is also an iterator. You `tee` the outer one successfully, but the inner iterators aren't copied so they get exhausted during the first loop. If you'll notice, your second loop *does* print out the keys for each group, it's just the groups themselves that are empty.

---

Separately, about `list` vs `tee` -- what `tee` does is fetch each item from the underlying iterator and save *n* copies of it. As each independent iterator advances, its copy of a particular item can get discarded. If you advance all your copies in lock-step, this is fine. But if you e.g. fully exhaust one copy without touching any of the others, you've essentially just created a `n` full copies of the original iterator.

As the documentation states:

> In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it! So is there any better way to achieve what I am looking for(looping twice over the groups efficiently in terms of memory)? I think I should call groupby twice and create 2 groupby iterators. But wouldn't that be a waste of computation? Isn't there a way to copy an iterator fully?

Comment: @Stuxen I'd just do the GroupBy twice. It's a pretty cheap operation, since it's just looking at the whether the next element matches. Copying the result may very well be slower. If you do want to try it, you could probably use `copy.deepcopy` successfully here.